# Oracle instant client 12c EZConnect Using tcps instead of tcp

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I download oracle instant client 12.2.0.1.0, I try to use sql loader to load csv data to the database. I can successfully load using following:

```
sqlLdr.exe userid=user/password@//192.9.200.228:1521/oracle ERRORS=4000 control=D:\temp\csma\xx_20190225.ctl log=D:\temp\csma\xx.log
```

However my production would only allow secured connection only (use tcps), can I use tcps by EZConnect? If not how can I connect using tcps using just the instant client (not full client)?

Comment: Presumably the people who set up your production system are the best people to ask. You can connect using a tnsnames alias with Instant Client.  The Instant Client installation instructions tell you where to put the Oracle Net configuration files. Or work through https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-secure-sockets-layer-authentication.html#GUID-85027CCD-62A0-4E95-8B02-020745D50900 :)

Comment: @ChristopherJones thx for your reply. So for the secured connection of oracle instant client, I cannot use EZConnect? I must use tnsname.ora and oracle wallet? I checked out your link and also google and no such information found for EZConnect for secured connection.

Comment: @ChristopherJones, thx for your advice, I am successfully to use wallet, tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora to connect to the server by secure connection using sql loader! You may write your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instant Client based applications can connect using a Net Service Name from a tnsnames.ora file. The Instant Client installation instructions (eg. [the instructions for Linux x64](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html#ic_x64_inst)) tell you where to put the Oracle Net configuration files.  Create the default location, put the files there, and update the connect string in your application.

With Oracle 19c, the Easy Connect syntax was extended to be 'Easy Connect Plus' so you specify things like the wallet location in-line, see the  [Understanding the Easy Connect Naming Method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netag/configuring-naming-methods.html#GUID-B0437826-43C1-49EC-A94D-B650B6A4A6EE) in the Oracle Net 19c documentation.  No Instant Client 19c has been released yet.